# Error: Must Declare the Scalar Variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset, prepared-statement

Here's my code:

```
Public Function selectReturnsByUserId( limit As Integer, userid As String ) As DataSet 



    Dim sql As String = " SELECT TOP " & limit & " pr.ProductId, p.Title, p.Barcode, pr.ScanDate, pr.UserId, pr.ReturnStatus" & _
                        " FROM " & tablename & " pr " & _
                        "   INNER JOIN " & StaticValues.TABLENAME_PRODUCT & " p ON pr.ProductId = p.ProductId" & _
                        " WHERE pr.UserId = @UserId"

    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand( sql )

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@UserId", userid ) 

    Return _select( cmd )

End Function
```

Which Calls:

```
Protected Function _select(ByVal cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand) As DataSet

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim myAdapter As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection().ConnectionString)
    myAdapter.Fill( ds, tablename )

    Return ds

End Function
```

And when I try to run it, I get this error:

*Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId"*

On this line:

```
myAdapter.Fill( ds, tablename )
```

How can I fix that line?

Thanks

Comment: Your capitalization is very wrong.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never passed the parameter to the SqlDataAdapter.

You should change the `_select` method to use the original `SqlCommand`, or to copy its parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't overly understand what you mean.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Matthew: What do you think happens to your SqlParameter?

Comment: `Dim myAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)`

Comment: Not a very informative answer. How about a link or example?